# Footer not staying at the bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This seems to be the most perplexing issue of all time, at least for me. Knowing that this page, aside from the header is broken - I have copied the HTML and tried to carefully remove the WordPress related jazz so you get the html  of the page.

[JsBin Live Page](http://jsbin.com/kiyebajese/1)

What I want you to focus on is the footer sitting in the middle of the page. I remove `position:absolute` and it sort of moves down.... It needs to stay at the bottom of the page.

This [is `position:fixed`](http://output.jsbin.com/nenulohuhe/1) this is the only way it stay at the bottom, but see how the footer follows you? **I don't want that**.

You might say, do `min-height: 100%` That is not what I want either because then the container, row and column classes that have height of 100% do not work.

What I am trying to accomplish is: [this type of layout.](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/v6p7hjhy/2/) But as you can see the footer rides up...

**Yes I have tried `position:relative` as well:** [check out `position:Relative`](http://jsbin.com/qekuhoretu/2/edit?html,css,output)

So as you can see The Live page I linked you too, from everythin gI read on the internet is the right way to achieve [this type of layout.](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/v6p7hjhy/2/), How ever I must be doing something wrong ...

### Update 1

Before you suggest I am missing divs, I have validated through a div checker for all of MY example and the divs are correct. I am not missing any divs. This is  a **pure css issue**

Before you mark this a duplicate of x, y and z - I have provided three examples of the positions I have tried and none of them has worked:

- [position:absolute](http://jsbin.com/kiyebajese/1)
- [position:relative](http://jsbin.com/qekuhoretu/2/edit?html,css,output)
- [position:fixed](http://output.jsbin.com/nenulohuhe/1) - Not what I want. The footer MUST stay at the bottom of the page.

Finally, as stated `min-height: 100%` on the wrapper (or any other element) is not acceptable as an answer unless you can specify how I can achieve [this type of layout.](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/v6p7hjhy/2/)

Comment: What browsers you desire compatibility? Take a look at what [Flexible Box Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/WD-css-flexbox-1-20150514/) can do about it. If IE10+ is viable to you, go with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way i usually do this, is to add position: relative to html and position: absolute to the footer itself.

The main disadvantage that you have to set margin-bottom=footer-height for the body

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html {
                position: relative;
                min-height: 100%;
            }

            body {
                margin-bottom: 100px; // is equal to footer height
            }

            .footer {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;

                width: 100%;
                height: 100px;
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="footer">footer</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

See the result https://jsfiddle.net/jy0gsgm4/

Answer (score 0):

Removing height:100% from wrapper stops the spacing below the footer. 
This is happening because the total height is the 100% wrapper and the height of the navbar. I would suggest putting the navbar into the wrapper div.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of this method.

```
display: inline-block;
```

Pretty self explanatory. HTML **(Demo)**

```
<div class="verycoolwrapper">

<!-- tons of cool stuff on page -->

    <footer id="footerstay">Blah | Blah2 | Hey | Click Here | Copyright 2090</footer>

</div><!-- // end wrapper -->
```

CSS: **(Demo)**

```
.verycoolwrapper { 
    width: 960px;
    background: pink;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative; // child elements relative to this, no height needed
}

#footerstay { 
   // your styles
   width: 100%;
   height: 150px;
   background: #ccc;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Also, alternately; clear float should work for you.